# What kind of cell kill probabilities per division you get with chemotherapy?

Tags: cancer, chemotherapy

As I understand it, many chemotherapeutic drugs target cell division, with the theory that a constant kill probability per cell division kills fast-replicating cancer cells faster than slow-replicating healthy cells.

What kind of kill probabilities per cell division event are useful in chemotherapy? Could a human typically tolerate, for example, 5% of cell divisions leading to apoptosis?

Answer (score 4):

The average human is rumoured to have around [30,000,000,000,000 cells](https://www.healthline.com/health/number-of-cells-in-body) in their body.

[Apoptosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoptosis) kills around 60,000,000,000 cells a day.

This is 0.002%, so I imagine a 5% kill rate would be at least fairly painful.